# How do I allow a parameter to be multiple types?

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I am sorry if this is a stupid question. I'd like to hand in a parameter that can either be a File or a string that I can then use to create a File. This is what I have so far:

```
public class DefaultOptions {

  public File setChooser(JFileChooser chooser, dir) {

  }

}


DefaultOptions dOptions = new DefaultOptions() {
  public File setChooser(chooser, dir) {
    if (!(dir instanceof java.io.File)) {
      String ds = dir.toString(); 
      File wd = new File(ds);
    } else {
      wd = (File) dir;
    }
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(wd);
  }
}
```

What signature can I use for this line:

```
  public File setChooser(JFileChooser chooser, dir)
```

If there is no way to do this, how can I simplify this?

Comment: Look into method overloading.

Comment: Which parameter would you like to set to String/File?

Comment: public File setChooser(JFileChooser chooser, Object dir) and type cast.

Comment: it is a very common pattern to do: `public File setChooser(String dirName) { setChooser(new File(dirName)); }` i.e. overloading the method and then delegating to the most specific (or to a hidden impl.) version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Object`:

```
public File setChooser(JFileChooser chooser, Object dir) {
    // ...
}
```

However, as pointed out in the comments, method overloading would <del>probably</del> definitely be better:

```
public File setChooser(JFileChooser chooser, String dir) {
     // handle String case
}

public File setChooser(JFileChooser chooser, File dir) {
     // handle File case
}
```

Comment: Using `Object` is pretty ew. Interesting suggestion, I guess, but method overloading is *definately* better.